# Publishing status rejected on playstore. Eligibility Issue. App does not meet the anti-SMS phishing use case criteria

Tags: google-play

After rollout, My apps has been rejected, and I got email from google PlayStore support. But I still not get a hint.

here is the message:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see... I must submit relevant documentation through this: 
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/sms_permissions 
to obtain a pre-qualification from Google.